# Does changing Application Insights Config triggers a app pool recycle

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I need to update application insights instrumental key on one of vm we have on azure. It's part of production environment and pointing towards a wrong AI at the present.

Would updating app insights instrumental key going to trigger anything and effect users using the system at all ?

Not able to find anything on google.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing instrumentation key in ENV variable or inside ApplicationInsights.Config? Either way, updating it here wont affect the application.i.e this won't trigger app pool recycle.

However, please note that Application Insights SDK won't pickup the new instrumentation key either. (Until app is restarted)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet Entire application insights SDK code is open source hosted in Github. (I dont have any links stating the above though)